# Listing the most recent files

Tags: unix

I am trying to list the most recent files in another file. I have passed a parameter for retention period as 5 which is denoted by ADAYS.
But the following line of code is not giving any result.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
cd /app/test &&  find . -type f -name "*.dat" -mtime +${ADAYS} -exec ls -l >> /app/test/clean.log {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
cd /app/test && find ./*.dat -mtime +${ADAYS} -exec ls -l >> /app/test/clean.log {} \;
```

I have considered ".dat" file must be a regular file, You can add **-type f** if required.

Comment: No Mayur, this also didn't work. I am not getting the content in the file. Only blank file is being created.

Comment: I have tested above command on my local machine and it has worked well. Please kindly check values for **${ADAYS}**. I have tested it with **-mtime +2**.

Comment: No Mayur, it is still creating a blank file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the most recent 5 days files. The you should use -${ADAYS} instead of +${ADAYS}.

Negative sign

```
cd /app/test &&  find . -type f -name "*.dat" -mtime -${ADAYS} -exec ls -l >> /app/test/clean.log {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this?

```
cd /app/test && find ./*.dat -mtime +${ADAYS} -exec ls -l {} \; >> /app/test/clean.log
```

Don't forget to replace `${ADAYS}` with the desired value like **5** or whatever